# Does the word "qualifications" when used in situations related to job application, refer only to educational qualifications?

Tags: meaning

I came across this mail(abridged version) on the Images section of Google search, which was sent by the management of an unnamed company in Bay Area to an individual who had submitted his/her Resume in response to a job advertisement:

> Your current **qualifications** do not match those needed for our
>   current openings

Is the word qualifications in this context referring only to educational qualifications or does it include work experience as well?

Comment: Did you look up *qualifications* in a dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are a first-time job seeker, one of the most important qualifications a potential employer has in mind is a "related" job experience.

[Qualification](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/qualification), as defined in Merriam-Webster, it definitely includes "a type of experience" that makes someone suitable to do a particular job or activity.